# Emacs: log the time required for typing commands

Tags: logging, emacs, keyboard, duration, typing

I'm an Emacs novice. I'm currently in the middle of learning the basic commands for navigation, editing etc.

Some key-combinations take me longer to complete...they usually require either more keys to be pressed or a higher degree of finger-position acrobatics :). I'm wondering if anybody knows if there is an existing Emacs plugin that:

1. Recognises when the user has begun typing a command (e.g. 'C-' something or 'M-' something) and records the time at that instant, then
2. waits until the user has finished typing the command (i.e. the point at which the command is recognised, before the command is actually executed) and records that time too, then
3. appends some simple logging info to a configurable file (e.g. writes 'command description', 'keys', 'entry duration') for that particular occurrence.

Why? Perhaps it's overkill, but it would probably save me time in the future if I were able to analyse such a log file and determine which commands have a high usage frequency as well as a long completion time. Such commands could be bound to keys that are simpler for my humble fingers to reach, for example :).

It could be a nice learning exercise for me to write this myself, but I'd probably prefer to save the time if a solution already exists.

Comment: In addition to your request, you may be interested to know how often you type a command (just duckduckgo for «emacs command frequency»). And have you heard about Prelude emacs ? I never tried it but the blog of the guy suggests that this is a very useful emacs conf, especially for novices. https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, take this lisp code:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-t") 'timed-key-seq)

(defvar timed-keys-hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

(defun timed-key-seq ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((t-beg (current-time))
         (key (read-key-sequence "command:"))
         (t-end (current-time))
         (t-diff (time-subtract t-end t-beg))
         (data (gethash key timed-keys-hash)))
    (if data
        (destructuring-bind (times . time) data
          (puthash key (cons (1+ times) (time-add time t-diff))
                   timed-keys-hash))
      (puthash key (cons 1 t-diff) timed-keys-hash))
    (call-interactively (key-binding key))))

(defun anb-report ()
  (interactive)
  (let (entries)
    (maphash (lambda (key data)
               (push
                (format "%s:\t%sx = %s ms\n"
                     key (car data)
                     (format-time-string "%3N" (cdr data)))
                entries))
           timed-keys-hash)
    (message (apply #'concat entries))))
```

The disadvantage is that you need to bind `timed-key-seq` to something,
I'd suggest <kbd>C-t</kbd>. And then you just prefix all your commands by <kbd>C-t</kbd>.
Maybe someone can suggest a `defadvice` that will make sure that this function will
be called each time without having to prefix it.

Use `anb-report` to generate the report. It will show you how many times you called
each combination and how many milliseconds they took together.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I'll need a while to digest/understand this, but it looks like it's in the right direction.  If I understand correctly, the reporting here must be invoked for each Emacs 'session'. I would probably want the data to be collected over many days/weeks, so I guess I could modify your code to have each entry append to a file instead. The key-binding issue is also a bit concerning...having to hit an extra combination kind of defeats the purpose of trying to increase up my keyboard efficiency, but I guess it would only be for the times when I'm doing analysis.

Comment: Note that it doesn't time you pressing `C-t`. The timing starts afterwards.